# use mysql query result as the data of flexbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-flexbox

Good day to every one, I just surfing on the internet and find some solution about, when the user tries to type any thing on the textbox it has a auto suggest word, then lucky i found the **flexbox** it's suites all what im looking for, except of the one thing, because Im lock of knowledge in the ff lang. like javascript jquery, i dont know how to set it up and i dont know how to set its database. but i have this guide http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox#config , after a couple of minutes, combining all the code. i create this:
**index.php**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flexbox.min.js"></script>  
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="..\css\jquery.flexbox.css" /> 
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function() { 
        $('#fb').flexbox('query.php');  
    });  
</script>
<body>
<form action="result.php" method="post">

        <div id="fb"></div>

</form>
</body>
```

but my very very big problem is how to link the result of my query in query.php in the index.php. this is my **query.php**

```
mysql_select_db('activity');
mysql_query('select per_name from myproject');
?>
```

and in my myproject table is has two fields per_id and per_name, per_id(int) auto_increment per_name(varchar-100). thank you readers and helpers, sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send the list as json so use `json_encode()` and json format is

> The call to results.aspx is ajax, and should return a JSON string in the format shown below.
>
> The “id” property is a string or integer, and is the value submitted when the form is submitted
>   (like the “value” attribute of the html  tag)
>
> The “name” property is a string or integer, and is the text displayed for each result, and when
>   a result is selected (like the text between the html  open and  close tags)

according to the [docs](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox)

so,try this

query.php **updated**

```
$records=array();
$result=mysql_query('select * from myproject');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result){
   $records[id]=$row['per_id'];
   $records[name]=$row['per_name'];
}
echo json_encode(array('results'=>$records));
```

Comment: nothing happen its only a textbox with an arrow on the side ;-(

Comment: is there anything else in your query.php ??? check your firebug console.. if there is any error

Comment: still it has no display of output when i type inside the textbox

Comment: im sure that i link the header correctly and then when i try to run or refresh nothing change, thank you for ur concern

Comment: updated my answer... check  the `json_encode` part... and why am i getting a downvote ??

Comment: what console? im just using notepad++

Comment: i mean console in your firefox firebug...link here http://getfirebug.com/.. recommend you to use this.. very helpful for developers.. especially for javascript errors and all..anyways did u try my update ??